# Failing to cover the code and pass the test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am a beginner in unit testing. I am trying to write a test script, but I am stuck. I'd like to understand what I am doing wrong.

```
public ConvertExcelDocumentResponse ConvertExcelDocument(ConvertExcelDocumentRequest request)
        {
            var logger = Bootstrapper.Resolve<ILogger>();

            ConvertExcelDocumentResponse response = new ConvertExcelDocumentResponse();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.FileName) &&
                System.IO.Path.GetExtension(request.FileName).ToLowerInvariant() == ".xls" &&
                request.FileContent != null && request.FileContent.Length > 0)
            {
                response.FileContent = _httpClient.ConvertExcelDocument(request.FileContent, request.FileName);
                response.FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(request.FileName) + ".xlsx";
                response.Success = true;
            }
            else
            {
                logger.LogError("Unable to convert Excel Document '" + request.FileName + "' only .xls files are allowed.");
                response.FileContent = new byte[] { };
                response.Success = false;
            }
            return response;
        }
```

Here is my test:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Test to Convert XLS to XLSX
        /// </summary>
        [TestCategory("DocumentService")]
        [TestMethod]
        public void Test_ConvertExcelDocumentResponse()
        {
            byte[] filecontent = new byte[] { };
            string filename = "file";

            using (ShimsContext.Create())
            {
                ConvertExcelDocumentRequest excelDocumentRequest1 = new ConvertExcelDocumentRequest()
                {
                    FileName = "filename",
                    FileContent = new byte[] {},
                };
                ConvertExcelDocumentRequest excelDocumentRequest2 = new ConvertExcelDocumentRequest()
                {
                    FileName = "",
                    FileContent = new byte[] {},    
                };

                ShimDocumentService.AllInstances.ConvertExcelDocumentConvertExcelDocumentRequest = ((@this, Success) =>
                {
                    return new ConvertExcelDocumentResponse()
                    {
                        FileContent=filecontent,
                        Success = true,
                        FileName = filename,
                    };
                });
                ShimHttpClientBase.AllInstances.ConvertWordDocumentByteArrayString = ((@this, fileContent, fileName) =>
                {
                    return fileContent;
                });

                //Act
                ILogger logger = Bootstrapper.Resolve<ILogger>();
                var docService = new DocumentService();

                //IDocumentService DocumentService = Bootstrapper.Resolve<IDocumentService>();
                var excelResponse1 = docService.ConvertExcelDocument(excelDocumentRequest1);
                var excelResponse2 = docService.ConvertExcelDocument(excelDocumentRequest2);

                //Assert
                Assert.AreEqual(excelResponse1.FileContent, filecontent );
                Assert.AreEqual(excelResponse1.FileName, filename);
                Assert.IsTrue(excelResponse1.Success, "Expects true");

                Assert.AreEqual(excelResponse2.FileContent, filecontent);
                Assert.AreEqual(excelResponse2.FileName, filename);
                Assert.IsTrue(excelResponse2.Success, "Expects true");
            }
        }
```

This is passing the test but code coverage is 0%. I don't know where I am going wrong. I tried covering filename = null and few other conditions. not sure why it isn't covering my code

Comment: Hi @SharanaJyothiB, welcome SO. Hard to tell but one thing that does stand out to me is that your unit test should not be pulling the `IDocumentService` instance from the `Bootstraper`. You should be creating the instance to test within the test itself.

Comment: Why does code coverage matter? Having high code coverage **does not** mean that your code has no bugs, or that the test cases you've written are covering valid scenarios and themselves are well-written. Focus on writing good tests that cover your requirements, not on coverage. Then review coverage to see if there are any obvious gaps in your testing, and write additional tests to cover those gaps.

Comment: Sometimes automated tools and processes care quite a bit about code coverage. Making good tests is important, making sure the unusual cases also don't blow up matters too.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll need to also write a test where the filename is null or empty. That way you will cover the code in the else block.

Increasing code coverage often involves making your test exercise pieces of code that are not likely to be normally hit.

Comment: It looks like there are a couple things going on in the new version. It looks like most importantly, you're no longer actually testing the class you want to test, but are using a 'shim' to imitate that class. That would explain why your code coverage went to 0 where it used to be 60%. The second observation here is that this should be implemented as two separate tests - one test would cover the normal success case, and the other test would verify that the 'Success=false' gets set appropriately. It looks like your test expects 'success' each time, which isn't what you want.